# Docker containers can't access remote database

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-21.04

My backend consists of:

1. A NodeJS/Express app,
2. A Redis service.

The app depends on redis, so the latter always gets started before the NodeJS app. Both containers get added to the same bridge network.

The point is, after starting both containers, the NodeJS app can't fetch data from a remote database. `exec`ing into the running container shows that `ping` command reports 100% packet loss, any attempts to `apk add` anything hang - in other words, there's no access to the network. `resolv.conf` shows local DNS address (127.0-something), the same as in the host server. However, the server uses `resolvectl` and there are no problems to access any external source.

When a copy of the deployment runs on a different server (Ubuntu 18.04), all checks from above yield the same output (100% packet loss, same `resolv.conf` content, etc.), but the app **can** access the remote database! The two differences: working backend gets deployed by Gitlab pipeline on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, not working one gets deployed manually and on an Ubuntu 21.04 server.

Can it be something with user permissions maybe? The same ports on both servers are open, the same `Dockerfiles` are used for building. I'm running out of ideas what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Are you able to ping any outside IP, if not, on what network is your docker ?
If you able to ping an outside IP, it maybe the DNS, which you could specify one before launching your docker container using the `--dns` flag

Comment: I can't ping any external IP from any of the containers, 100% packet loss every time. Also, adding the `--dns` flag with the IP of the DNS used by the host server doesn't change anything, unfortunately. What's interesting, pinging a URL from inside a container reports both the URL and its IP. Is it somehow cached maybe, or updated while the request gets sent?

Comment: Could you use tracert on your host checking that it is not using some kind of proxy / vpn ?

Comment: For sure it is. But in one case the backend works as intended (the instance deployed by Gitlab pipeline), and in the other it can't connect to the network. Both servers operate in the same domain, so the proxy settings shouldn't matter here.